# Is there an implementation of range() which is not limited to integers?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, range, generic-programming

The Python `range()` built-in function is limited to integers.

I need a more generic function of similar signature `range(start, stop, step)`, where `start`, `stop` and `step` may be of **any types** given that:

- result of (possibly multiple) addition of `step` to `start` is defined,
- both `start` and the result mentioned above can be compared with `stop`.

The function may be used (for example) to obtain a sequence of days of the year:

```
range(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1),
      datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1),
      datetime.timedelta(1))
```

I know I can easily write such function by myself. However, I am looking for efficient existing solutions in some popular package (like numpy or scipy), working with both Python 2 and Python 3.

I have already tried to combine `itertools.takewhile` with `itertools.count`, however the latter seems to be limited to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple generator. The following example works with floats, integers and datetime.

With datetime you just need to clearly specify the exact date (1 Jan 2016) not just 2016 and clearly specify the time delta (timedelta(days=1) not timedelta(1))

```
import datetime

def range2(start,stop,step):
    value = start
    while value <= stop:
        yield value
        value += step

for date in range2(datetime.datetime(2015,1,1),datetime.datetime(2016,1,1),datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
    print(date)
```

As for off-the-shelf solutions there is `arange` in numpy but I haven't tested that with datetime.

```
>>> from numpy import arange
>>> arange(0.5, 5, 1.5)
array([0.5, 2.0, 3.5])
```

Comment: Thanks. I know the generator trick, but it is DIY solution. Seems that `arange` works with `datetime` and `timedelta`, and is almost what I am looking for, but it requires also `-` and `/` operations to be defined, and `/` must return a number. I have corrected the `datetime` objects, however the call to `timedelta` is correct: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects.

Comment: Agreed. Why go looking for a solution that is in a pre-released library when you have something that works.. All coding is a DIY solution.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen nothing but that I knew how to do it

Comment: @scotty3785 I did not requested pre-relased library, did I?

Comment: Coding is a DIY solution. There isn't a non-DIY solution to this problem. As I mentioned in my answer, arange in numpy is also a way to do the same thing.

Comment: @scotty3785: Sadly, `numpy.arange` requires additional operations to be implemented by the class, thus I stick to DIY.

Comment: If you feel like accepting the answer, that'd be great.